# Function template mistaken for operator<

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How do I get the following code to compile?

```
template<typename T> struct A{
  template<int x> void foo() { }
};

template <typename T> void bar()
{
    A<T> a;
    a.foo<22>(); //< error: invalid operands of ... to binary ‘operator<’
}

int main(void)
{
    bar<int>();
}
```

On the line with the error message, I would like to call `a.foo` from inside `bar`, setting the appropriate template.

Based on the error, the compiler wants to parse the line as (I think):

```
(a.foo < 22) > ()
```

How can I get it to parse as a function call and not as a `<`?

Seems like something like the most vexing parse but I've never seen it before.

Comment: You need to use `a.template foo<22>();`.